# USB ports's ID of a computer

Tags: c++, windows, qt, usb

I am programming with Qt Creator in C++.  My question: 1.- How can I obtain a fixed ID that belongs to each USB port of a computer (in Windows , 64 bits)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/how-usb-devices-are-assigned-container-ids, [Is there a way to obtain USB port IDs via Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325065/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-usb-port-ids-via-win32-api)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: Make a sticker for each number (from 0 to N-1) and put one over each port.  You have fixed IDs.  Now what?  Did you mean to identify the port where a particular device is connected?  Turn off power to one that you identify?  Just count the number of ports the user's computer has (this is actually far more difficult than you think)?

Comment: I'm trying to make an application for desktop for my friend. The necesity of my friend is to have a program that can identify each port because his job is copy to USB pendrives information, and he is front the serious problem of more than 16 USB pendrives each hour, that is a great confusion, as you can see. I think fixed IDs related to each USB port is more secure to him that  IDs related to the pendrives or other thing

Comment: I think is very usefull the comments of all you and I thanks it. It's very special the intervention of S.S.Anne, but I'm a new student of Qt, and the Microsoft libraries that I should use such as ntoskrnl.lib (and ntoskrnl.exe ) generate a problem in Qt Creator:
error: skipping incompatible E:\.../ntoskrnl.lib when searching for -lntoskrnl